# NodeJS + Docker + OSX

Tags: node.js, docker, macos, zsh

I'm trying to run from Docker a simple "hello world" in NodeJS, following a video tutorial. This is my first attempt in nodejs and in Docker so I'm sure I miss something obvious but passing through the video compared to the code I wrote many times, I still can't find the error.

Locally it works fine, but in Docker is unable to run. In Docker Desktop the container becomes green and immediately gray again.

I've tried to change the path many times, thinking that the problem is there but without any clue. I really haven't the experience to investigate further, please help me to solve the issue.

My Dockerfile

```
FROM node:16
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package.json .
RUN npm install
COPY . ./ 
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["npm", "run", "dev"]
```

package.json

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.18.1",
    "node": "^18.5.0"
  },
  "name": "contratti",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "prova",
  "main": "App.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node App.js",
    "dev": "nodemon -L App.js"
  },
  "author": "jegor",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.19"
  }
}
```

App.js

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

app.get("/", (req,res) => {
  res.send("<h2> Ciao ciao ..</h2>");
});

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server running at ${port}`));
```

ZSH

```
docker run -v $(pwd):/usr/src/app -p 3000:3000 -d --name contratti contratti
```

Error returned

```
> contratti@1.0.0 dev
> nodemon -L App.js

/usr/src/app/node_modules/.bin/node: 1: /usr/src/app/node_modules/.bin/node: �����: Input/output error
/usr/src/app/node_modules/.bin/node: 3: /usr/src/app/node_modules/.bin/node: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
```

Comment: Do you have a `.dockerignore` with `node_modules` in it ?

Comment: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/nodejs-docker-webapp/#dockerignore-file

Comment: The `.dockerignore` file won't matter because the `docker run -v` option hides everything in the image and replaces it with the content from the host directory.  Running `brew install node` might be an easier way to run your local Javascript code without the complexities Docker brings.